# Sitecore 7.2, Media Framework 1.4 and HTML5 Player

Tags: media-library, brightcove

We are on Sitecore 7.2 and using Media Framework 1.4. This works fine with flash players.

But when we are trying to use an HTML5 player for Bright cove Videos it is not working and throwing errors like:

> The video you are trying to watch is currently unavailable. Please check back soon.

Does anyone have any ideas about what would cause this error? Also does media framework 1.4 support HTML5 players?

[image: HTML5 Player Error]

Answer (score -1):

Flash has been phased out of many browsers and platforms over the last several years. Brightcove has prepared a number of tools, guides and services to help make your transition from the legacy (Flash-based) player to new (HTML-based) player as easy as possible.

Media framework 1.4 supports the HTML5 players with the Video object as mentioned below:

```
                    <video class="video-js"
                           controls
                           data-application-id
                           data-embed="default"
                           data-account=<your brightcove data account>
                           data-player=<your brightcove player>
                           data-video-id=<your brightcove video id>>
                    </video>
```